# Unable to return response from function

Tags: python, json

I am working on a simple script to return a JIRA Case ID after an issue is submitted to JIRA.

I have a created an issue function that takes JSON parameters from a RESTful web service and it then passes on said parameters to create a case in JIRA automatically. Here's a snippet of the function I've written:

```
 def create_issue():

    issue = {
        'summary': request.json['summary'],
        'project': request.json['project'],
        'desc': request.json['desc'],
        'issuetype': request.json['issuetype']
    }

    issue_dump= json.dumps(issue)
    issue_source = json.loads(issue_dump)

    summ = (issue_source["summary"])
    proj = (issue_source["project"])
    desc = (issue_source["desc"])
    type = (issue_source["issuetype"])

    print(f"{summ}")
    print(f"{proj}")
    print(f"{desc}")
    print(f"{type}")


    issue_dict = {
            'project': proj,
            'summary': summ,
            'description':desc,
            'issuetype':type,
    }

    new_issue = jira.create_issue(fields=issue_dict)

    #Used to print response of new_issue
    print(f"{new_issue}")

    response = {'JIRA ID': new_issue}

    return jsonify(response),201
```

I added a `print` statement of `new_issue` and I see the JIRA ID (e.g. ID-2) does appear on the console, but for some reason when I try to include it into my JSON response as a variable, I get the Object of type Issue is not JSON serialisable. I have tried substituting the `new_issue` variable in my response JSON with another defined test variable and it works just fine.

I am using Flask to host the web services.

Am I missing entirely on something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code behind the Jira library it looks like the create_issue method returns an Issue object which contains lots of information. When you try to print it, it prints the first human readable value it can find in the object.

Try this instead:

```
response = {'JIRA ID': new_issue.key}
return jsonify(response),201
```

The code for the returned Issue class can be found [here](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/master/jira/resources.py) beginning on line 404

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment. So could you please share what type does new_issue return?.

```
print(type(new_issue))
```

JSON requires a key, value Pair. Since you've unpacked the new issue variable inside another dict the types are probably incompatible.

Comment: Hi , this is the response i am getting :   print(type(new_issue))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Did you try printing the response variable to check whether  the dict gets printed properly?. Also try doing  `dict(jira_id=new_issue)` print that and see what the output is.